# SSD plugged in via adapter

Tags: disk

I recently bought Unitek Y-1096 Adapter.
Unfortunately, when I plug SSD with it, it doesn't work.
SSD seems to works properly via SATA III.
It was partitioned, it has only one ext4 partition that covers the whole disk.

Output of uname -a:

```
Linux fedora 5.18.13-200.fc36.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jul 22 14:03:36 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

output of lsblk:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    1    0B  0 disk 
zram0       252:0    0    8G  0 disk [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:0    0  1.9T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0  600M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  1.9T  0 part /home
                                     /
```

In fdisk -l /dev/sda doesn't even show up.

Output of dmesg:

```
[  +0.002331] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  +1.028746] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Asm      225              0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  +0.000241] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  +0.000338] sd 10:0:0:0: [sda] Media removed, stopped polling
[  +0.000943] sd 10:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that plugging it **directly** to the motherboard was the solution.

Comment: Doesn't work on raspberry pi 4B though... Original power supply and output of dmesg is almost the same as in the question (3 last lines are exactly the same). Some googling suggests that it is problem with power. Any suggestions are welcome.